# fatal: could not read Username for Visual Studio<URL>: No such device or address

Tags: git, version-control, azure-devops

Can anyone help me with the below issue? I am facing it on Jenkins.

```
+ git commit -m Added file
[PROD-Backup-NHS 9d4222d] Added file
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 newfile1
+ git push -u origin PROD-Backup-NHS
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://nestle-globe.visualstudio.com': 
No such device or address
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Other commands used:

```
git branch -a
git checkout PROD-Backup-NHS
touch newfile1
ls -lrt ${WORKSPACE}
git config --global user.email "user.name@nestle.com"
git config --global user.name "user name"
git add .
git commit -m "Added file"
git push -u origin PROD-Backup-NHS
```

Comment: You're not using bitbucket, perhaps change the tag? Double check that the VSTS address is correct.

Comment: Yes, I am not using bitbucket. I am using VSTS as a repository. I checked URL it is correct one only.

Comment: Try using authentication via ssh instead of https.

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding ssh key in the VSTS but didn't work. Not sure what is the issue here.

Comment: git branch -a

        git checkout PROD-Backup-NHS

        touch newfile1

         ls -lrt ${WORKSPACE}

         git config --global user.email "user.name@nestle.com"
         git config --global user.name  "user name"

         git add .

         git commit -m "Added file"

         git push -u origin PROD-Backup-NHS

Comment: Did you also change the remote's url?

Comment: No, I didn't change remote URL. I am using existing URL.

Comment: Which is still the https address? If you've successfully set up an ssh key, why not change the remote url to ssh instead?

Comment: Yes, I tried with ssh but not working getting Connection Timed Out error with SSH.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support/help-troubleshoot-ssh-key-authentication-team-foundation-server/

Comment: Hi. This article visualstudio.com/team-services/support/ didn't help me, getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **provide credential** when pushing to VSTS git repo.
PAT or alternate credential can be added in the repo URL:

#### Option 1: Add PAT in VSTS git repo URL

The format of the URL should be:

```
https://Personal%20Access%20Token:{PAT}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame}
```

#### Option 2: Add alternate credential in VSTS git repo URL

The format of the URL should be:

```
https://{secondary username}:{password}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame}
```

**When you add the VSTS git repo as a remote (`origin`) for the local git repo**, you need to use:

```
git remote add origin https://Personal%20Access%20Token:{PAT}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame}
```

Or

```
git remote add origin https://{secondary username}:{password}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame}
```

And since the `origin` url for now not contains credential. If you do not want to change the origin url, you can push by any of below commands:

```
git push -u https://Personal%20Access%20Token:{PAT}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame} PROD-Backup-NHS
git push -u https://{secondary username}:{password}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame} PROD-Backup-NHS
```

Comment: Getting and error: 

            git push -u https://{secondary username}:{password}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com PROD-Backup-NHS

            fatal: unable to access 'https://{secondary username}:{password}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/': Port number ended with 'V'

Comment: Sorry for ignore the project name and repo name in the url. Please use `git push -u https://{secondary username}:{password}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame} PROD-Backup-NHS` instead.

Comment: @Bobby Can you push to VSTS git repo successful now?

Comment: Getting same error
                fatal: unable to access 'https://{secondary username}:{password}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/test/ PROD-Backup-NHS': Port number ended with 'V'

Comment: When I run through Jenkins getting an error like this:

fatal: repository ' 'https://{secondary username}:{password}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/test/ PROD-Backup-NHS' not found

Comment: Million Thanks to @Marina Liu . It is working now with the below command:
git push -u https://Personal%20Access%20Token:{PAT}@nestle-globe.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame} PROD-Backup-NHS

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer (click √ symbol on the left of the answer). And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. :-)